# UIWebView auto rotation corrupts web view content (screenshots inside)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, rotation

i'm having a problem with UIWebView auto-rotating.
the web view straches alright but the content is not.
as you can see in the bottom screenshot there is a black margin, and i know it's the webview since i can see the scrollers when i scroll.

the view controller has:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    return YES;
}
```

the webview has full auto resizing mask, and the view is auto-resizing subviews.

i tried a bunch of tricks from stackoverflow and google but none of them worked.
this happens only on some sites, but if i open the problematic sites in mobile safari or even ios opera browser, it rotates correctly.

EDIT: an example of a problematic site: *http://m.calcalist.co.il*

the webview is set in the interface builder and loading with this code:

```
[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://m.calcalist.co.il"]]];

scalesPageToFit = YES; // doesn't help
```

Thanks!

[image: before rotation]

[image: after rotation]

Comment: Can you plz add your code related to webview ? How do you create and put ?

Comment: Could you provide the address of one such site?

Comment: an example of a problematic site: http://m.calcalist.co.il

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the web view's `scalesPageToFit` property to `YES`.

If you are generating the HTML yourself, then you can also set the `viewport` meta tag.

If the page has already set the viewport, you can set your viewcontroller to be the web view's delegate and change it like this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSString *javaScript = @"var metatags = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); \
    for(cnt = 0; cnt < metatags.length; cnt++) { \
        var element = metatags[cnt]; \
        if(element.getAttribute('name') == 'viewport') { \
            element.setAttribute('content','width = device-width; user-scalable = yes'); \
        } \
    }";
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

    if ([self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.zoom = 1.0;"];
    else
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.zoom = 1.5;"];
}
```

Comment: The site you mention (m.calcalist.co.il) has the viewport set to a width of 320, so it's not going to get any wider than that. It's the page design that's wrong, not your implementation.

Comment: Updated my answer to show how to break free from a restrictive viewport.

Answer (score 3):

Set the frame in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` and then set the meta tags.

Also you can set this property of `UIWebView`:

```
webView.autoResizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Comment: this solution works for me. not the picked answer one

Comment: Yes, this works but theres a mistake in code: autoResizingMask => autoresizingMask, with the 'R' not capitalized.